# Trdion docs 2013 SP2 | DXA 2.1 Publishing Getting failed at deployment Phase

Tags: 2013, dxa, dxa-2.1, tridion-docs, elasticsearch

I have Trdion Docs 2013 SP2 installed. Everything including Elastic Search, Content Delivery and CMS is on the same machine.

Publishing works only when IshSearchIndexDeployStep tag in deployer-conf.xml is disabled.
I see below errors when I try to enable indexing for the elastic search.

Here is what I see in deploer logs

> [image: Blockquote]

In the CMS Event Logs I get below Message

> Event type    PUBLISHDITADELIVERY
>   Action  Deployment failed
>   Description DITADELIVERYCHECKREMOTESTATUS failed because one of the packages failed to deploy (4 failed, 0 success). Check the event data for more information.
>   Status  Failed
>   Event level Exception
>   Process ID  5172
>   Thread ID   30
>   User ID Admin
>   Hostname    EC2AMAZ-T0GVJN3
>   Event data type Xml
>   Event data size 28382
>   Event Monitor Content
>   
>     
>       Failed to deploy 'ish422183-1-66560-20190614142753177.zip' because of 'Could not load configuration.'
>       [
>     {
>       "Id": "Bootstrap-StartTransaction",
>       "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:16.1+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>       "Status": "SUCCESS",
>       "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.34+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>       "StatusMessage": null,
>       "Steps": [
>         {
>           "Id": "IshStartTransactionStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:17.413+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.323+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshUnzipStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:16.243+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:17.353+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         }
>       ]
>     },
>     {
>       "Id": "Ish-Process",
>       "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.387+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>       "Status": "FAILED",
>       "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:22.317+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>       "StatusMessage": "Failed to execute pipelineId: 'Ish-Process' for 'ish422183-1-66560-20190614142753177.zip' because of Could not load configuration.",
>       "Steps": [
>         {
>           "Id": "IshSearchIndexDeployStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:22.29+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "IN_PROGRESS",
>           "EndTime": null,
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshBinaryDeployStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:19.123+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:22.23+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshIndexDeployStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.797+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.843+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshTOCDeployStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.733+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.78+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshPublicationDeployStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.403+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.607+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshPageDeployStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.967+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:19.093+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshPublicationMappingRegistrationStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.623+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.687+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshComponentDeployStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.873+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.937+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   ]
>     
>     
>       Failed to deploy 'ish422183-2-66560-20190614142753177.zip' because of 'Could not load configuration.'
>       [
>     {
>       "Id": "Ish-Process",
>       "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.323+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>       "Status": "FAILED",
>       "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:22.52+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>       "StatusMessage": "Failed to execute pipelineId: 'Ish-Process' for 'ish422183-2-66560-20190614142753177.zip' because of Could not load configuration.",
>       "Steps": [
>         {
>           "Id": "IshPublicationDeployStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.357+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.607+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshPublicationMappingRegistrationStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.64+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.717+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshPageDeployStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:20.967+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:22.45+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshBinaryDeployStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:22.467+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:22.503+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshIndexDeployStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.81+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.907+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshTOCDeployStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.75+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.78+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshComponentDeployStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.937+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:20.923+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshSearchIndexDeployStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:22.503+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "IN_PROGRESS",
>           "EndTime": null,
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         }
>       ]
>     },
>     {
>       "Id": "Bootstrap-StartTransaction",
>       "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:16.04+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>       "Status": "SUCCESS",
>       "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.307+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>       "StatusMessage": null,
>       "Steps": [
>         {
>           "Id": "IshUnzipStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:16.243+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:16.87+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshStartTransactionStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:16.923+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.277+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   ]
>     
>     
>       Failed to deploy 'ish422183-3-66560-20190614142753177.zip' because of 'Could not load configuration.'
>       [
>     {
>       "Id": "Bootstrap-StartTransaction",
>       "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:16.1+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>       "Status": "SUCCESS",
>       "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.307+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>       "StatusMessage": null,
>       "Steps": [
>         {
>           "Id": "IshUnzipStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:16.26+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:16.34+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshStartTransactionStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:16.357+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.293+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         }
>       ]
>     },
>     {
>       "Id": "Ish-Process",
>       "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.34+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>       "Status": "FAILED",
>       "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:21.833+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>       "StatusMessage": "Failed to execute pipelineId: 'Ish-Process' for 'ish422183-3-66560-20190614142753177.zip' because of Could not load configuration.",
>       "Steps": [
>         {
>           "Id": "IshPageDeployStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:20.75+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:20.813+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshPublicationDeployStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.357+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.623+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshSearchIndexDeployStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:21.483+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "IN_PROGRESS",
>           "EndTime": null,
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshPublicationMappingRegistrationStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.657+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.78+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshTOCDeployStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.797+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.937+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshComponentDeployStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:19.78+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:20.733+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshBinaryDeployStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:20.953+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:21.367+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshIndexDeployStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.953+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:19.51+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   ]
>     
>     
>       Failed to deploy 'ish422183-4-66560-20190614142753177.zip' because of 'Could not load configuration.'
>       [
>     {
>       "Id": "Bootstrap-StartTransaction",
>       "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:16.04+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>       "Status": "SUCCESS",
>       "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.357+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>       "StatusMessage": null,
>       "Steps": [
>         {
>           "Id": "IshStartTransactionStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:16.333+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.34+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshUnzipStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:16.087+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:16.273+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         }
>       ]
>     },
>     {
>       "Id": "Ish-Process",
>       "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.387+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>       "Status": "FAILED",
>       "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:22.317+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>       "StatusMessage": "Failed to execute pipelineId: 'Ish-Process' for 'ish422183-4-66560-20190614142753177.zip' because of Could not load configuration.",
>       "Steps": [
>         {
>           "Id": "IshSearchIndexDeployStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:22.07+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "IN_PROGRESS",
>           "EndTime": null,
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshTOCDeployStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:19.493+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:21.387+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshPageDeployStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:21.897+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:21.947+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshPublicationMappingRegistrationStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.907+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:19.377+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshPublicationDeployStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.417+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:18.89+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshIndexDeployStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:21.4+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:21.497+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshBinaryDeployStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:21.973+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:22.02+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         },
>         {
>           "Id": "IshComponentDeployStep",
>           "StartTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:21.787+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "Status": "SUCCESS",
>           "EndTime": "2019-06-14T14:28:21.85+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
>           "StatusMessage": null
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   ]

I am using IQ combined service and it is registered in discovery service capabilities as
[image]

My elastic search.YML looks as
[image]

I suspect it is failing while connecting to Elastic search. I have default index installed and I can browse it as http://localhost:9200/udp-index and same is configured in bootstrap.json as

> {
>     "configs": [
>       {
>         "index": "udp-index",
>         "file": "elasticsearch.json"
>       },
>       {
>         "index": "udp-configuration",
>         "file": "configuration-elasticsearch.json",
>         "initial-documents": "locale-config.json"
>       }
>     ],

Is there anything I am missing in the configuration?

Comment: Can you check and update iq service log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cd_client_config of deployer was missing

```
<QueryClient Class="com.sdl.delivery.iq.query.client.rest.RestQueryClient" />
```

It got resolved after adding this tag in the cd_client_config.